# How to get embedding elements in mongodb using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

my json data is like bellow:

```
"scores": [
    {
        "type": "exam",
        "score": 1
    },
    {
        "type": "quiz",
        "score": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "homework",
        "score": 3
    },
    {
        "type": "homework",
        "score": 4
    }
]
```

I'm using below code to retrieve only score.

```
while(cursor.hasNext())
    { 

        BasicDBObject acc=( BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        acc.get("scores");
        for(int i=0;i<=acc.size();i++)
        {
            ((BSONObject) acc.get(i)).containsField("score");
        }
        //System.out.println(acc);

    }
```

I'm getting null point exception. What is wrong?

Comment: exactly for which line of code u r getting null pointer exception

Comment: ((BSONObject) acc.get(i)).containsField("score");

Comment: You'll want to loop over the result from `acc.get("scores")`. Now you are looping over the document itself.

Comment: can you help using code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you will have to do:

```
 while(cursor.hasNext())
    {

        BasicDBObject acc=(BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        BasicDBList scores = (BasicDBList) acc.get("scores");
        for(int i=0;i<scores.size();i++)
        {
            BasicDBObject score = (BasicDBObject) scores.get(i);
            System.out.println(score.get("score"));
        }

    }
```

Few notes:

- You need to loop the scores array (I assume it's array) and not the `BasicDBObject` itself. Hence you need to cast it to `BasicDBList`. Otherwise you will have to defend against Cast Exceptions
- Java arrays elements are from 0...size()-1. So use `<` and not `<=` in your loop.